# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fighter.id_fighter' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having trouble renaming the column's foreign key to the record name which makes it easier for the user to understand (`line <td> {{ $msf->id_fighter == $msf->fighter->id ? $msf->fighter->name : '' }} </td>`), But it is giving me the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fighter.id_fighter' in 'where clause'
> SELECT * FROM `fighter` WHERE `fighter`.`id_fighter` = 2 AND `fighter`.`id_fighter` IS NOT NULL

- `master.php`

```
    @foreach ($master as $msf)
        <tr>
            <td> {{ $msf->id }} </td>
            <td> {{ $msf->name}} </td>  
            <td> {{ $msf->martial_art }} </td>  
            <td> {{ $msf->nacionality }} </td>  
            <td> {{ $msf->genre->value }} </td>
            <td> {{ $msf->height }} m </td>  
            <td> {{ $msf->weight }} kg </td>
            <td> {{ $msf->id_fighter == $msf->fighter->id ? $msf->fighter->name : '' }} </td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ url("delete-master/$msf->id") }}" method="POST">
                    <a href="{{ url("update-master/$msf->id") }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-arrows-rotate"></i>&nbsp;Update</a>
                    @csrf @method('DELETE')
                        <x-primary-button class="ml-3"> {{ __('Delete') }} </x-primary-button>  
                </form>
            </td>  
        </tr>   
    @endforeach
```

- `MasterModel.php`

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\Enums\Genre;
    
    class MasterModel extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        protected $table = 'master';
        protected $primary_key = 'id';
        public $timestamps = false;
        protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'martial_art',
            'nacionality',
            'genre',
            'height',
            'weight',
            'id_fighter',
        ];
        protected $casts = [
            'genre' => Genre::class
        ];
        public function fighter(){
            return $this->hasMany(FighterModel::class,'id_fighter','id');
        }
    }
```

- `FighterModel.php`

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\Enums\Genre;
    
    class FighterModel extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        protected $table = 'fighter';
        protected $primary_key = 'id';
        public $timestamps = false;
        protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'martial_art',
            'nacionality',
            'genre',
            'height',
            'weight',
        ];
        protected $casts = [
            'genre' => Genre::class
        ];
    }
```

- `MasterController.php`

```
    public function index()
    {
        $master = MasterModel::paginate(5);
        $count_masters = DB::table('master')->distinct()->count('name');
        return view('master.master', compact(['master','count_masters']));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `id_fighter` is on the Master model, then Master really doesn't have many fighters, it only has one. You need to change your `fighter` relationship to be a `hasOne()`, and switch the columns around since the second parameter is the fighter table, the third is the master table.

```
public function fighter(){
     return $this->hasOne(FighterModel::class,'id','id_fighter');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, returned the result I wanted.